# Functional approach to get vetorial product of a polygon

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce

I'm using a formula to archive the area of a parallelogram

Mathematical formula to vetorial product: `((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) + (x2 * y3 - y2 * x3) + (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4) + (x4 * y1 - y4 * x1)) / 2`

The thing is: I'm doing it "by hand":

```
(points[0].x * points[1].y - points[0].y * points[1].x) +
(points[1].x * points[2].y - points[1].y * points[2].x) +
(points[2].x * points[3].y - points[2].y * points[3].x) +
(points[3].x * points[0].y - points[3].y * points[0].x)) / 2
```

Is there a way to archive the same result using something like `reduce`, trying to avoid a classic `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use modulo to access the next (or wrapped around) point while `reduce`ing:

```
const vProd = points.reduce((sum, point, i, arr) => {
  const { x, y } = arr[(i + 1) % arr.length];
  return sum
  + point.x * y
  - point.y * x
}, 0);
```

Not sure if it's better though; the function of original 4-liner, while lengthy, is quite clear

Comment: `If initialValue isn't provided, reduce() will execute the callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index.`-- In that case how this will work if you are not providing initialValue

Comment: No, the accumulator (or `sum` here) is intended to be a number, the current sum (else `vProd` wouldn't resolve to a number as intended)

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Just extracted the operations to avoid mixing operators. `const res = (point.x * y) - (point.y * x)
    return sum + res`